# How do I delete part of a path between the nearest two intersections in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

I'm fairly new to using Inkscape and have been trying to make an SVG version of a logo I had made for myself a while back in a 2D CAD/CAM program exported to a bitmap.

[image]

So far this is all I have been able to get to by using guide circles to create the curved corners, however I'm not entirely sure how to delete the arcs within the actual main logo.

[image]

Is there a way to delete the parts of the circle paths that intersect another path such as the main logo? I haven't been able to figure out how to use the path operations properly for this.

Comment: You have created a perfect reference that defines the final shape. Your most useful option in the long run is now to get some control over the pen tool and snappings to points. With that skill you redraw your logo over the quide drawing in 2 minutes.

Comment: @user287001 I suppose, but I've only just started off using Inkscape properly so I've not quite gotten to grips with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular question on how to remove part of a circle:

First, convert your circle object to a path using /Path -> Object to path/. This will transform the circle into a path with 4 nodes. Conveniently, these nodes are at top, bottom, left and right of the shape.

With the path selected, call the /Edit nodes/ tool (bound to <kbd>F2</kbd>). Click on a quadrant you wish to remove (or shift-click on several path sections). Now apply the /Delete segment/ tool on the toolbar, and the segment is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a best answer on how to do precisely what you asked, but I think your approach is overly complex.

The raster image you already have could be used as your guide, there is no need to draw new guides.  Simply lock the raster image on its own layer, dim the opacity to something like 50%, then create a new layer on top.

Drag and drop vertical/horizontal guides around the edges of the logo.

Use the Pen tool to draw straight lines. At the corners just draw straight diagonal lines.  When you have finished, the corner segments can be clicked and dragged into a curve by using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool.

for example:

[image: Example using raster image as guide]

Comment: Actually, this might work a bit better. I'll try this method and see if I get any better results.